# Merge SQL Server Management Studio 2008 tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

What about merging these tags: [ssms2008](/questions/tagged/ssms2008) **>** [ssms-2008](/questions/tagged/ssms-2008) ?

And remove [ssms2008](/questions/tagged/ssms2008). All other tags related to SQL Server Management Studio have dash before version number, for example [ssms-2012](/questions/tagged/ssms-2012) and [ssms-2005](/questions/tagged/ssms-2005).